# Proof of replacing union of sets with sum of sets.

Tags: induction, solution-verification

There is an expression $$\bigcup_{n=0}^m A_n = \sum_{n=0}^m B_n \qquad (1) $$ where: $$B_0 = A_0$$
$$B_n = \bar{A}_0 \cap \bar{A}_1 \cap ... \cap \bar{A}_{n-1} \cap A_{n}$$

I am confused with the proof of it. I try to proof by induction:

1. For $m = 0$ the expression is obvious.
2. Let's assume that the expression is correct, therefore the expression must be correct for $m+1$:
   $$\bigcup_{n=0}^{m+1} A_n = \sum_{n=0}^{m+1} B_n \qquad (2)  $$

transforming the last expression (assuming that (2) is correct), we are getting:

$$ \bigcup_{n=0}^{m+1} A_n = \sum_{n=0}^m B_n + B_{m+1} = \bigcup_{n=0}^m A_n + B_{m+1} $$

so:

$$  A_{m+1} = B_{m+1} $$

but it is obviously wrong. Where am I making a mistake?

Comment: You cannot "subtract" a set from both sides of an equation. For instance, $A=\{2,3\}, B=\{3\}, C=\{1,2\}$, then $A\cup C=B\cup C$ but $A\neq B$.